# Why use ByVal in a function?

Tags: vb.net

I am confused with `ByVal` and `ByRef`. I have this code here:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim var As Integer = 2

        abcref(var)
        MessageBox.Show(var)


        abcval(var)
        MessageBox.Show(var)

    End Sub
    Function abcval(ByVal var)
        var = var + 1
        Return var
    End Function

    Function abcref(ByRef var)
        var = var + 1
        Return var
    End Function

End Class
```

`Byval` does not perform the calculation I want, but instead takes the value within the `Button_click` event. `ByRef` performs the correct calculation of `2+1 = 3`. Since `ByVal` is suppose to be safer, how can I use `ByVal` here?

Comment: Use `var = abcref(var)`, you're returning the claculated value but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: `Since ByVal is suppose to be safer` -- No.  ByVal has a *different use case.*  It is not inherently safer.

Comment: `abcval` *will* perform the desired calculation *if* you don't call `abcref` **first**.  When you call `abcref` first, it changes the value of `var`, so when you call `abcval` after that, `var` actually equals `3`, not `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as you noted, passing `ByVal` is safer, the function context doesn't chnage the value of the outer `var` variable. So you should actually capture the function result but not expect that variable value is changed after `ByVal` call:

```
varResult = abcval(var)
MessageBox.Show(varResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Byref` is passed by value, so it is essentially altering the value of your variable. If you use `ByVal` in this case, you would need to assign the value of the function to your variable. In otherwords

`var = abcval(var)`